# Making request from browser empty tab

Tags: javascript, http, browser

When I make request from browser's empty tab (using devtools console and `fetch method` ) it fails. 
I receive these request headers:

```
Provisional headers are shown
Learn more
Referer
sec-ch-ua: "Not?A_Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="108", "Google Chrome";v="108"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

I know that browser has CORS. But I don't understand how it works with empty tabs. 
What browser set as `origin` and so on. 
Also I think that in this case browser doesn't show all request headers. 
So maybe you can tell to me how to get them and how it works or you can share a good resource to read.

Comment: If you write a minimal Node.js web server: `require("http").createServer(console.log).listen(80)` and make a `fetch` request in the console from an empty tab, you will see nothing: no request is actually made.

Comment: *I receive these request headers* - you send these, you receive **response headers**

Comment: *When I make request from browser's empty tab (using devtools console and fetch method ) it fails* - can't reproduce